# PHP Multidimensional Array to Two Column HTML Table

Tags: php, arrays, loops, multidimensional-array, foreach

I have an array called `$data` and I would like to display a two column html table,

- `tableHeader` on the left hand column.
- `tableData` on the right hand column.

A `print_r($data)` displays the following

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [tableHeader] => ID
            [tableData] => 104
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [tableHeader] => Member Number
            [tableData] => not available
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [tableHeader] => First Name
            [tableData] => Peter
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [tableHeader] => Last Name
            [tableData] => Keys
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [tableHeader] => Address
            [tableData] => 17 main road
        )

    [5] => Array
        (
            [tableHeader] => Email
            [tableData] => P3TER@HOTMAIL.CO.UK
        )

    [6] => Array
        (
            [tableHeader] => Post Code
            [tableData] => LDN 1
        )

    [7] => Array
        (
            [tableHeader] => City
            [tableData] => London
        )

    [8] => Array
        (
            [tableHeader] => Year Graduated
            [tableData] => 0000-00-00
        )

    [9] => Array
        (
            [tableHeader] => Subject Studied
            [tableData] => Comp
        )

    [10] => Array
        (
            [tableHeader] => Telephone Number
            [tableData] => 123123
        )

)
```

I have tried the following `foreach` loop but I keep receiving an error message;

> Message: Undefined variable: value

```
<table class="table">
  <thead>
    <? foreach ($data as $value): ?>
    <tr>
      <th scope="col"><?php echo $value['tableHeader']; ?></th>
    </tr>
    <? endforeach; ?>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <? foreach ($data as $value): ?>
    <tr>
      <th scope="col"><?php echo $value['tableData']; ?></th>
    </tr>
    <? endforeach; ?>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Unpossible!!!!!

Comment: First I would advise against using SHORT PHP (<?) tags. Secondly, using output PHP tags (<?=) increases readbility.

If you want tableHeader in a column on the left and tableData in a column on the right, why not just output <tr><td><?=$value['tableHeader']?></td><td><?=$value['tableData']?></td></tr>.

Comment: Try replacing `<? foreach` with `<?php foreach` (unless you've actually got short tags turned enabled)... I suspect if you view source you'll actually see `<? foreach` in the code - whereas `<?php echo $value` **is** being picked up by the interpreter and therefore complaining that `$value` hasn't been defined.

Comment: Thanks for the comments guys, all makes more sense now! If someone wants to add an answer I can accept.

Comment: Do you want a separate table for each sub-array? If not, then you are not going to get a 2-column table since there are multiple header names. If you want a single table then there will be a column for each `tableHeader`. Alternatively,  the table column headers are for 'headerName' and 'dataValue' for example, then in each row you could insert the values for each item in a sub-array.

Comment: No @seantunwin I simply want all the data in the same table, two colums, left and right. I think the issue has been addresses already - short tags

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like the short tags are not working, because when the php code inside of the foreach loop is executed, it does not recognise the $value variable, because it was never parsed by php.